# How to add type annotation to abstract classmethod constructor?

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, abstract-class, mypy, typing

I'd like to type-annotate abstract class method witch behave as a constructor. For example in the code below, `ElementBase.from_data` is meant to be a abstract classmethod constructor.

tmp.py

```py
from abc import abstractmethod, abstractclassmethod
import copy
from typing import TypeVar, Type

ElementT = TypeVar('ElementT', bound='ElementBase')

class ElementBase:
    data: int
    def __init__(self, data): self.data

    #@abstractmethod
    def get_plus_one(self: ElementT) -> ElementT:
        out = copy.deepcopy(self)
        out.data = self.data + 1
        return out

    @abstractclassmethod
    def from_data(cls: Type[ElementT], data: int) -> ElementT: # mypy error!!!
        pass

class Concrete(ElementBase):
    @classmethod
    def from_data(cls, data: int) -> 'Concrete': # mypy error!!!
        return cls(data)
```

However, applying mypy to this code shows the following erros.

```
tmp.py:18: error: The erased type of self "Type[tmp.ElementBase]" is not a supertype of its class "tmp.ElementBase"
tmp.py:23: error: Return type "Concrete" of "from_data" incompatible with return type <nothing> in supertype "ElementBase"
```

Do you have any idea to fix this error? Also, I'm specifically confused that the part of `get_plus_one` does not cause error, while only the part of `abstractclassmethod` does cause the error.

FYI, I want to make the abstract method constructor generic becaues I want to statically ensure that all subclass of `ElementBase` returns object with it's type when calling `from_data`.

[EDIT] comment out `abstractmethod`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `mypy` doesn't understand the `abstractclassmethod` decorator. That decorator has been deprecated since Python 3.3, as the `abstractmethod` and `classmethod` decorators were updated to play nice together. I think your code will work properly if you do:

```
@classmethod
@abstractmethod 
def from_data(cls: Type[ElementT], data: int) -> ElementT:
    pass
```

It's unrelated to your type checking issues, but you probably also want to change `ElementBase` to inherit from `abc.ABC` or to explicitly request the `abc.ABCMeta` metaclass if you want the abstractness of the class to be enforced by Python. Regular classes don't care about the `abstractmethod` decorator, and so as written, you'll be able to instantiate `ElementBase` (or you could if it's `__init__` method didn't have an unrelated issue).

And another peripherally related note on this kind of type hinting... [PEP 673](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0673/) will add `typing.Self` in Python 3.11, which will be a convenient way for a method to refer to the type of object it's being called on. It should play nicely with classmethods without requiring you to jump through any hoops. With it you'd be able to write this much simpler version of the annotations:

```
@classmethod
@abstractmethod
def from_data(cls, data: int) -> Self:
    pass
```